# Vertically centre TextView between 2 existing elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout, gravity

I have a RelativeLayout in my Android project which displays to a simple custom dialog.  I have a title at the top, some text in the middle and a button at the bottom.  All I'm trying to do is center the text between the *bottom of the title* and the *top of the button*.

When it's centered, the distance between the top of the TextView and the bottom of the title should be the same as the distance between the bottom of the TextView and the top of the button.

To achieve this, I've placed a frame layout within my relative layout and placed it 'above the button' and 'below the title.

What I get is this:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here is my XML (Note, I set the text of the main TextView programaticaly).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="40dp">        
    </TextView>   

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Click Me"        
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbk"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"        
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </Button>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@id/title" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30dp" 
            android:textColor="#000000">        
        </TextView>       

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a possible solution to your problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/light_blue400"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:background="@color/light_blue100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="18dp"
            android:text="Text centered vertically"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the results (I have colored the background to show the different areas).

- white: main Relative Layout
- light blue 400: Title TextView
- light blue 100: Relative Layout for centered TextView

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks @eldivino, I had to move the button code above the embedded layout as it was giving me an error.  However it did work and it led me to identify the problem (as I was comparing your code to mine line by line) which was a silly error on my part - I had a 50dp padding added to the top of my textview (android:paddingTop="50dp"), I removed that from my original code and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have the chance to try it, but something like this should work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:gravity="fill">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="40dp"></TextView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/text"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:paddingRight="18dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonbk"
    android:text="Click Me"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:gravity="fill"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="40dp">        
</TextView>   

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="Click Me"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"        
    android:textStyle="bold">
</Button>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@id/title" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:paddingRight="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30dp" 
        android:text="Hi Im textView"
        android:textColor="#000000">        
    </TextView>       

</FrameLayout>
```